# R correlation in a loop with one dynamic variable and based on group variable using ddply

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table, plyr, correlation

I want to generate correlation and it may be basic but I am not able to get it. Need your help!!

I am trying to generate correlation for user specified variables (i.e. the variable on which correlation needs to be generated is not fixed. Could different in different scenarios and hence taking inputs and storing in a vector **str_char** )

For each of these variables I need to generate correlation with **value** variable and the correlation should be based on the groups in **type** variable.

Below is the sample dummy data. My actual data has many more columns and rows.

```
library("plyr")
library("data.table")

set.seed(1200)
id <- 1:100
bills <- sample(1:20,100,replace = T)
nos <- sample(1:80,100,replace = T)
stru <- sample(c("A","B","C","D"),100,replace = T)
var1 <- sample(1:80,100,replace = T)
var2 <- sample(1:80,100,replace = T)
v1 <- sample(1:80,100,replace = T)
v2 <- sample(1:80,100,replace = T)
a1 <- sample(1:80,100,replace = T)
b1 <- sample(1:80,100,replace = T)
type <- sample(1:7,100,replace = T)
value <- sample(100:1000,100,replace = T)

df1 <- as.data.table(data.frame(id,bills,nos,stru,var1,var2,v1,v2,a1,b1,type,value))

#storing the variables for which need to generate correlation. This would change in different scenarios and one would need to update this variable.
str_char <- c("bills","nos","stru","var2","v1","b1")

len <- length(str_char)

#Since the variables are not fixed using for loop. To tackle the requirement of generating correlation by group using ddply

corr<-data.frame()
for (i in 1:len){
  df1$var1 <- df1[,which(colnames(df1) == str_char[i])]
  var1 <- str_char[i]
  temp1 <- ddply(
    df1
    , .(type)
    , summarize
    , var1=cor(value,var1,method="spearman")
  )
  corr <- as.data.frame(cbind(corr,temp1))
}
```

This generates a empty data frame for **corr**. Not sure where I am going wrong. I wanted to have the type in rows and each of these variables in columns with the cell having the correlation value.

Once I have the data frame with correlation  values, I want to identify the variables where the correlation is > 0.2 and store them in a vector.

Could you please help by suggesting where I am going wrong OR suggest some better way out to meet this requirement.

Thank you !!

Comment: Would you be interested in a base `R` solution, or does it have to be `plyr`/`data.table`?

Comment: @LAP, base R solution should fine as I do not have a working solution from plyr / data.table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a base `R` solution using `split` to generate a list of subsets, calculate the correlations and `rbind` them together in the way you want. I guess there will be a more sophisticated approach using `data.table`, but for now it'll do the trick.

Generate a `data.frame` from the data you provided:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id,bills,nos,stru,var1,var2,v1,v2,a1,b1,type,value)

> head(df1)
  id bills nos stru var1 var2 v1 v2 a1 b1 type value
1  1     4  74    A   36    1 54 75  9 31    2   139
2  2     8  36    D   75   73 10 72 43 55    6   743
3  3    10  12    B   64   60 39 22 62 40    4   574
4  4    11  33    B   11   73 69 33 29 38    1   409
5  5    10  32    B   73   66 37 34 29 58    6   620
6  6    12  39    D   38   39 40 56 68 29    6   539
```

Create subsets using `split`:

```
subsets <- split(df1, df1$type)
```

Use a nested `lapply` solution to loop over the variable names in `str_char`:

```
corlist <- lapply(subsets, function(x) lapply(str_char, function(y) cor(x[,"value"], as.numeric(x[,y]), method = "spearman")))
```

Use a nested `do.call` to create the matrix of correlation coefficients:

```
cormatrix <- do.call(rbind, lapply(corlist, function(x) do.call(c, x)))
```

Assign names to the columns:

```
colnames(cormatrix) <- str_char
```

Output:

```
> cormatrix
        bills         nos        var2          v1          b1
1 -0.58026951  0.16493506 -0.07664827  0.11627152 -0.05595326
2  0.02646100  0.22246750  0.40308468  0.38943918 -0.10121018
3 -0.11389551  0.36446564 -0.16438528  0.00000000 -0.04100238
4 -0.45645233 -0.21585955 -0.19560440  0.28351648 -0.08580863
5 -0.18596606 -0.23776224 -0.06304738 -0.03508794  0.39860140
6 -0.72346726 -0.04175824  0.24862501 -0.30583077 -0.31718139
7 -0.02649032 -0.08810594  0.48398529  0.30143033  0.50165047
```

To add the type and the names of up to three variables with correlation coefficient > 0.2 (sorted by value) to the `cormatrix`, use this:

```
maxvector <- apply(cormatrix, 1, function(x) sort(x[which(x > .2)], decreasing = T))
maxvector <- lapply(maxvector, function(x) names(x)[1:3])
maxvector <- lapply(maxvector, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
maxvector <- lapply(maxvector, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ","))
cormatrix <- cbind(type = 1:7, cormatrix, maxvector)
```

Result:

```
> cormatrix
  type bills       nos         stru        var2        v1          b1          maxvector    
1 1    -0.5802695  0.1649351   0.08202645  -0.07664827 0.1162715   -0.05595326 ""           
2 2    0.026461    0.2224675   0.2196833   0.4030847   0.3894392   -0.1012102  "var2,v1,nos"
3 3    -0.1138955  0.3644656   -0.117698   -0.1643853  0           -0.04100238 "nos"        
4 4    -0.4564523  -0.2158596  -0.3755155  -0.1956044  0.2835165   -0.08580863 "v1"         
5 5    -0.1859661  -0.2377622  0.3944463   -0.06304738 -0.03508794 0.3986014   "b1,stru"    
6 6    -0.7234673  -0.04175824 0.2858584   0.248625    -0.3058308  -0.3171814  "stru,var2"  
7 7    -0.02649032 -0.08810594 -0.05718863 0.4839853   0.3014303   0.5016505   "b1,var2,v1"
```

Edit: I've also reincluded `stru` by converting with `as.numeric` (Thanks @Uwe).

Comment: thank you for your answer. This works. Could please confirm what is "c" in do.call doing? Also could you help with the second part of the question, I want to select and store the column names in a new column where the correlation value is > 0.2. These column names need to be top 3 columns with correlation value > 0.2

Comment: The `c` is telling `do.call` to use the function `c()` to create a vector.

Comment: Please further explain the second question. Do you want to extract the top 3 correlation values (or the respective column names) for each of the 7 rows separately?

Comment: So I want to create a new column in **cormatrix** say "selected" which would have column names for top 3 correlation values in each row. So for 1st row it would be blank as non of them are > 0.2 for 2nd row it would contain **var2,v1,nos** (if you see it is sorted by the values). For the 3rd row it would contain **nos** as this is the only column having correlation > 0.2. Hope this can be achieved. If we can not have them in on column then it is fine to have them in 3 different column say **selected 1** ,**selected 2** , and **selected 3**

Comment: Thank you for answer. Some how I am not able to implement to my data, only difference I can see is that my cormatrix is a dataframe, if I convert it to a matrix still it does not work.....Would you know anything on this?

Comment: yes it is working fine on the data provided and I managed to replicate on my data. The issue was with converting the data frame to matrix. I was missing on the column names and by usage of **dimnames()** I managed to get it worked. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

With `data.table` no "sophisticated trick" is required. It can be done by using the `by` parameter (instead of `split()`) and the `.SDcols` parameter to specify the columns to be used in the call to `cor()`. So, it's pretty much straightforward `data.table` syntax:

```
# without stru because it is factor not numeric
str_char <- c("bills", "nos", "var2", "v1", "b1")
df1[, lapply(.SD, function(x) cor(value, x, method = "spearman")), 
    keyby = type, .SDcol = str_char]
```

> ```
>     type       bills         nos        var2          v1          b1
> 1:     1 -0.58026951  0.16493506 -0.07664827  0.11627152 -0.05595326
> 2:     2  0.02646100  0.22246750  0.40308468  0.38943918 -0.10121018
> 3:     3 -0.11389551  0.36446564 -0.16438528  0.00000000 -0.04100238
> 4:     4 -0.45645233 -0.21585955 -0.19560440  0.28351648 -0.08580863
> 5:     5 -0.18596606 -0.23776224 -0.06304738 -0.03508794  0.39860140
> 6:     6 -0.72346726 -0.04175824  0.24862501 -0.30583077 -0.31718139
> 7:     7 -0.02649032 -0.08810594  0.48398529  0.30143033  0.50165047
> ```

```
# with stru after coersion of factor to numeric
str_char <- c("bills", "nos", "stru", "var2", "v1", "b1")
result <- df1[, lapply(.SD, function(x) cor(value, as.numeric(x), method = "spearman")), 
    keyby = type, .SDcol = str_char]
result
```

> ```
>     type       bills         nos        stru        var2          v1          b1
> 1:     1 -0.58026951  0.16493506  0.08202645 -0.07664827  0.11627152 -0.05595326
> 2:     2  0.02646100  0.22246750  0.21968328  0.40308468  0.38943918 -0.10121018
> 3:     3 -0.11389551  0.36446564 -0.11769798 -0.16438528  0.00000000 -0.04100238
> 4:     4 -0.45645233 -0.21585955 -0.37551547 -0.19560440  0.28351648 -0.08580863
> 5:     5 -0.18596606 -0.23776224  0.39444627 -0.06304738 -0.03508794  0.39860140
> 6:     6 -0.72346726 -0.04175824  0.28585837  0.24862501 -0.30583077 -0.31718139
> 7:     7 -0.02649032 -0.08810594 -0.05718863  0.48398529  0.30143033  0.50165047
> ```

Note that `keyby` is used instead of `by` to have the result in the same order as in [LAP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47431533/3817004) for comparison.

---

In addition, the OP has requested to append a new column to the result which contains the names of the 3 top variables with the highest `cor()` value > 0.2 for each `type`.

Finding the top 3 values can be most conveniently done after reshaping `result` from wide to long format:

```
# reshape from wide to long
melt(result, id.vars = "type")[
  # select by value
  value > 0.2][
    # order by descending value and pick the first 3 (if any)
    order(-value), toString(head(variable, 3L)), keyby = type]
```

> ```
>    type            V1
> 1:    2 var2, v1, nos
> 2:    3           nos
> 3:    4            v1
> 4:    5      b1, stru
> 5:    6    stru, var2
> 6:    7  b1, var2, v1
> ```

Appending to `result` is done by an *update on join*:

```
result[
  melt(result, id.vars = "type")[value > 0.2][
    order(-value), toString(head(variable, 3L)), keyby = type],
  on = "type", selected := V1][
    # beautify result
    is.na(selected), selected := ""][]
```

> ```
>    type       bills         nos        stru        var2          v1          b1      selected
> 1:    1 -0.58026951  0.16493506  0.08202645 -0.07664827  0.11627152 -0.05595326              
> 2:    2  0.02646100  0.22246750  0.21968328  0.40308468  0.38943918 -0.10121018 var2, v1, nos
> 3:    3 -0.11389551  0.36446564 -0.11769798 -0.16438528  0.00000000 -0.04100238           nos
> 4:    4 -0.45645233 -0.21585955 -0.37551547 -0.19560440  0.28351648 -0.08580863            v1
> 5:    5 -0.18596606 -0.23776224  0.39444627 -0.06304738 -0.03508794  0.39860140      b1, stru
> 6:    6 -0.72346726 -0.04175824  0.28585837  0.24862501 -0.30583077 -0.31718139    stru, var2
> 7:    7 -0.02649032 -0.08810594 -0.05718863  0.48398529  0.30143033  0.50165047  b1, var2, v1
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your solution in data.table. This helps !! Could you help with the second part of the question, I want to select and store the column names in a new column where the correlation value is > 0.2. These column names need to be top 3 columns with correlation value > 0.2. It would be great if you could guide on this one !!

Comment: Thank you very much !! This is also interesting and useful. I wanted to vote +1 for your edit but not able to,

Comment: Unfortunately, you can only give one upvote to each post ;-) Perhaps, you may split up a complex problem and post several questions, next time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tidyverse attempt:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  select(bills, nos, var2, v1, b1, type) %>% #select needed variables, one can also do: select(str_char, type), however `stru` is not numeric
  group_by(type) %>% #group by type
  do(correlation = as.data.frame(cor(.[1:5]))) %>% #correlation
  unnest(correlation)  %>% #convenient output
  gather(key, value, bills:b1) %>% #for easier pairwise removal
  filter(var != key)  %>% #remove self correlation
  arrange(type, var, key)
  #output 
   # A tibble: 140 x 4
    type    var   key       value
   <int> <fctr> <chr>       <dbl>
 1     1     b1 bills  0.01978168
 2     1     b1   nos -0.40581082
 3     1     b1    v1 -0.08507922
 4     1     b1  var2  0.15430381
 5     1  bills    b1  0.01978168
 6     1  bills   nos  0.21208062
 7     1  bills    v1 -0.15127493
 8     1  bills  var2 -0.02983736
 9     1    nos    b1 -0.40581082
10     1    nos bills  0.21208062
# ... with 130 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is interesting. I will need to understand tidyverse package !!